# Is it possible to implement anycast with IPv4 in Omnet++?

Tags: c++, networking, ipv6, ipv4, omnet++

I am thinking of implementing anycast. I have 2 network areas with ipv4  addressing schemes. IPv6 addressing scheme is used for anycast. So please give me some tips for implementing anycast mechanism in IPv4 addressing scheme.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with it. Do you want the devices on the same LAN, or do you want them on different networks?

Comment: I would have anycast for different networks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What IPv6 can do that IPv4 doesn't is anycast (identical addresses) on the same network.

Setting up anycast for IPv4 and IPv6 when on different networks is easy. You just let the routing protocol decide which network is closest. The same network is advertised from multiple places, and the routing protocol metrics will determine to which network your traffic gets sent. Should one of the networks, or a path to one of the networks fail, all the traffic destined for addresses on that network will automatically be sent to the identical, alternate network.

Comment: Ohh yes, that explains it. Ok just out of curiosity so when in the case of set of nodes in the same network how anycast can be implemented?